# How can I write to a file in array notation using Node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm trying to split text into an array and then ultimately create a new file with the contents of that array.

However, when I do this, the text file contains a comma-delimited list instead of using array notation.

Here is the code so far:

```
var input = "4 Every Dog Must Have His 66 Every Day,";

var lorem = function(text) {
  var textArray = input.split(' ');

  for (var i = textArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (textArray[i].match(/(\d+)$/)) {
      textArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  return textArray;

};

output = lorem(input);

var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("test", output, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`writeFile` expects `data` to be a `String` or a `Buffer`, so it is printing the `.toString()` representation of your array. This looks something like `"Every,Dog,Must"...`.

Wrap it with `JSON.stringify(output)` to get a nice JSON representation `"['Every','Dog','Must',....]"`.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by array notation? Isn't that a comma delimited string with brackets? Try this.

```
output = "[" + output.join(', ') + "]";
```

Comment: This totally works, but I think the most correct answer is using JSON.stringify(output).